# Formatting child text in expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

New to Java and Android development. I'm making an expandable `ListView` and want the text within child string to be formatted. At least for bold, underline and linebreak. Or any easier way to do that without deviating from the purpose.

```
String[] example = new String[] { "I want this text to have bold underline and linebreak" };
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to format text is to use `Html.fromHtml()` and standard HTML markup. Bold, italics, and underline are all supported.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This</b> <u>is a</u> <i>test</i>"));
```

Or, following your `String[]` example (assuming you add the HTML tags):

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(example[0]));
```